# To display 1st list-item value from mat-selection-list in another component by default

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular-components

I have 2 components called:

**1)list (used to display customer list)**

**2)detail (used to display customer details)**

These two components are generic components,So i am re using these components inside another component called **customer**.which will be displayed as shown in below image:

[image]

Here on clicking particular customer name(ex customer one) on `list` component, I am displaying that customer values(ex Name and age) on `details` component(i,e Customer details).This scenario working fine.

**But i want first list-item(i,e customer one) to be highlighted and its value(i,e name and age) to be displayed on the details component by default.** like this:

[image]

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/list-examples-mine-bmjfra?file=app/customer/customer.component.html) Link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can emit the first value once the `ListComponent` is loaded.

### ts

```
export class ListComponent {

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.contacts && this.contacts.length > 0) {
      this.select.emit(this.contacts[0]);  //<-- emit the first value
    }

  }
```

### html

```
  <mat-selection-list  #contact>
        <mat-list-option 
      [ngClass]="{selected : contact.name == currentContact.name}"  
      *ngFor="let contact of contacts">
            <a mat-list-item (click)="onSelect(contact)"><span>{{ contact.name }}</span> </a>
        </mat-list-option>
      </mat-selection-list>
```

Here is the working copy - https://stackblitz.com/edit/list-examples-mine-mgshnt

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is it possible highlight the first customer??

Comment: What class and where you want to put for highlighting ?

Comment: In the list component, Means the `first list-item (i,e customer-one)` should be `selected/highlighted` by default..

Comment: Check the updated answer and link. I added the class `selected` in `mat-list-option` but you can change as per requirement.

Comment: I have seen the `stackblitz` link,it's not highlighting the first customer.

Comment: I just want to change the 1st selected item 's  `(i,e customer one)` **background color** or **color**.

Comment: Updated the link. checknow

Comment: I got it,Thank you.

Comment: Actually i was previously tried this code to **highlight the customer-list**, from now your code i am bit confused ...:) Here is the link which i used **to highlight the customer list onclick** : `https://stackblitz.com/edit/list-examples-mine-btgyuq?file=app/list/list.component.scss`

Comment: You did not the add code for html and ts. Here is your modified code. https://stackblitz.com/edit/list-examples-mine-gta2rl

Comment: This is highlighting the 1st customer by default i,e fine but on clicking next customer the previous click is not going, **Means on clicking next customer previous customer is still highlighted**

Comment: Its because of your css issue.  check here https://stackblitz.com/edit/list-examples-mine-gta2rl. If you have any other issue, feel free to raise another query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183618/discussion-between-prashanth-gh-and-sunil-singh).